# Is this undefined behavior or not?

Tags: c++, standards

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    ~A()
    {   
        std::cout << "~A" << std::endl;
    }   
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int k;
    ~B()
    {   
        std::cout << "~B" << std::endl;
    }   
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A* p = new B();
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

The above doesn't cause memory leak though base destructor is not virtual and I know the reason.

But is this undefined behavior or not?

Say there won't be memory leak if derived class doesn't point to other dynamic data even though base destructor is non-virtual?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes it is**. Deleting an object of a derived `class` through a pointer to a base class with no `virtual` destructor is textbook UB.

**5.3.5/3:**

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a
>   base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall
>   have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be
>   deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.73)

Because it's undefined behavior, it doesn't really make sense to guess whether the code will leak or not. Just attempt to fix the code instead of predicting results.

Comment: Did you ever meet such code(derived class don't point to dynamic data) cause leaks?

Comment: @new_perl yes I did, but the derived class destructor was also freeing some memory.

Comment: That's sure to happen.But I'm talking about the case the derived class destructor doesn't need to free anything explicitly.

Comment: @new_perl then no. But this speculation is counter-productive. You should just make the destructor virtual. There's no point in trying to predict UB.

Comment: @new_perl also, it's not sure to happen. It's UB, nothing's sure.

Comment: Yeah ,I can guess the implementation is to create a structure with all the fields so `free` takes care of the derived data automatically.So this case should never cause leak actually.

Comment: If you really wish to encounter the UB, possibly memory leak, use multiple inheritance, cast to the second base class and delete that one. This will no longer be a valid memory manager pointer and may cause a leak and/or corruption.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since the static type (here it's `A`) differs from the dynamic type (`B` in your example) and there's no `virtual` destructor, it's an UB.

5.3.5/2 (5.3.5/3 in C++11):

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the
>   static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual
>   destructor or the behavior is undefined.