# Is that UB if we destory the class which the most base class is trivially destructible(or not) and it's derived class' destructor is virtual

Tags: c++, class, c++11, destructor

for better understand this problem, let's see the code1:

```
// code1
struct A {
    int e;
};

struct B : A {
    virtual ~B() { }
};

struct C : B {
    ~C() { }
};
```

as you can see, class A is trivially destructible
Q1: is the behavor is undefined if we destory the instance of the class C through the pointer of the class A in code1?
Q2: is the behavor is undefined if we destory the instance of the class C through the pointer of the class B in code1?

here is the another version, call it code2:

```
//code2
struct A {
    int e;
    ~A() { }
};

struct B : A {
    virtual ~B() { }
};

struct C : B {
    ~C() { }
};
```

for now, class A has a user-provided destructor. so the class A is not trivially destructible
Q3: is the behavor is undefined if we destory the instance of the class C through the pointer of the class A in code2?
Q4: is the behavor is undefined if we destory the instance of the class C through the pointer of the class B in code2?

I have read the standard ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E) [expr.delete]/3

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and **the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined**. In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

Q5: the standard said **the static type shall have a virtual destructor**, but what about the base class of that static type?

Comment: One question per post. You have 5 questions in your post.

Comment: @JasonLiam all of these questions are trying to explan one problem clearly, I don't think these questions can be asked separately

Comment: You might find it easier to forget the standard and think about what the compiler can do. If the compiler knows the definition of `A`, but not the definitions of `B` and `C`, what will the compiler do when deleting a pointer-to-`A`?

Comment: @JaMiT so when the static type is A and A doesn't have a virtual destructor no matter whether it's trivially destructible or not, it's UB? what about deleting a pointer-to-B?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will using delete with a base class pointer cause a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100644/will-using-delete-with-a-base-class-pointer-cause-a-memory-leak)

Comment: Also related: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/) [Is this undefined behavior or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775247/) [Multiple inheritance and polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796349/)

Comment: @iTruth Inventing irrelevant complications does not change what the standard says. Don't imagine it says more or less than it does. As you quoted "the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined". Where does it mention something related to trivially destructible? Where does it say anything about base classes of the static class making a difference? Find the static class, look at its destructor, and you know all you need to know.

Comment: @JaMiT thank you for your answer, I have readed all the post you given. unfortunately, all of these posts doesn't answer my question. I think my problem is slightly different. as you know, the class A in code1 is a POD class, so that I can pass it directly to C code. but can I derived a class from A that I can use OOP?

Comment: I don't understand what about JaMiT's answer doesn't answer your question, or what makes your situation "slightly different". POD doesn't matter. Deleting a `C` through a pointer to `A` when `A` doesn't have a virtual destructor is undefined behavior.  If that fact interferes with something else you're trying to do, you might be better served asking a question that actually gets into what you're attempting.

Comment: @NathanPierson not JaMiT's answer doesn't answer my question, I mean the link he post. he's answer has high reference value. for now I know deleting a C through a pointer to A when A doesn't have a virtual destructor is undefined behavior. but what about deleting a C through a pointer to B?

Comment: If a type has a virtual destructor the compiler will call the right destructor for a pointer of that type even if the instance is really of a derived class. (Practically, it will pick the destructor function pointer from VMT.) If it doesn't have a virtual destructor it will destruct the type of the pointer. (No entry in VMT.) So: Q1: Yes Q2: No Q3: Yes Q4: No Q5: If any base class has a virtual destructor: No otherwise Yes.

Comment: FYI: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/266185be0df26364)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

```
A* a = new C();
delete a; // UB
```

the static type is `A`. It doesn't matter that `B` makes its destructor virtual. The only destructor that is considered here is `A::~A()` (in both your code variations). Now, if you have this:

```
B* b = new C();
delete b; // not UB
```

the static type of `b` is not `A` but `B`. `B` however *has* a virtual destructor and will therefore destroy `C` first, then `B` and finally its base `A`. That is no different from a class hierarchy without virtual destructors when you destroy the most derived type:

```
struct X {};
struct Y : X {};
struct Z : Y {};
Z* z = new Z();
delete z; // destroys Z, then Y, then X (not UB)
```

for this to work there is little difference with trivial and non-trivial destructors.

To answer your final question: The static type you want to destroy must have a virtual destructor or be identical to the dynamic type. Otherwise everything ***above*** the static type will be erroneously overlooked. But types ***below*** the static type are statically known to be base classes of the static type, so a virtual destructor is not necessary.